# Refer shared resources in EAR from different WARs

Tags: web-applications

I have an EAR with multiple WARs in it and each WAR has same set of image/css/js folders.

Is it possible to take out the image/css/js folders and place them in EAR and then refer those files in all WARs?

Or is there a possibility to create another utility WAR which will hold all these shared resources and specific WARs will just load image/css/js from this utility.war ?

Any other solution or suggestion is also welcome.

Regards,
Satya

Answer (score 0):

Although we don't use EARs, i can give you a hint on how to reuse resources.
We're using the Apache Wicket framework, where resources are loaded from the Classpath and not from the filesystem. That means, they can be packaged into a JAR file - which can then be reused in the various .WAR files of yours.